# How to occupy something (in this case a wardrobe slot) in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm developing a wardrobe application that uses a database table called "entrances".

The program is used to organize a normal wardrobe storage where the storage can have different amount of numbers/slots to hang clothes on. When a customer comes up to the merchant, the merchant scans the customer's bar code and will then get a free number from the system to hang the customer's clothes on. But there can of course only be one entry for each number.

My entrances db could look something like:

```
ID | wardrobeNo | storeID | customerBarcode | deliveredTime | collectedTime
---+------------+---------+-----------------+---------------+--------------
1  | 1          | 1       | XX              | 20:12:55      | NULL
2  | 2          | 1       | XA              | 20:44:44      | NULL
3  | 1          | 2       | XZ              | 20:55:55      | NULL
4  | 2          | 2       | XC              | 22:22:22      | NULL
```

Later that day the same entries do still exist in the DB but they will now have a collected time if the clothes have been collected from the wardrobe on some of the numbers before people went home.

```
ID | wardrobeNo | storeID | customerBarcode | deliveredTime | collectedTime
---+------------+---------+-----------------+---------------+--------------
1  | 1          | 1       | XX              | 20:12:55      | 23:23:23
2  | 2          | 1       | XA              | 20:44:44      | NULL
3  | 1          | 2       | XZ              | 20:55:55      | 22:23:23
4  | 2          | 2       | XC              | 22:22:22      | NULL
```

I will then be able to see the occupied numbers with:

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE storeID = x AND delivered NOT NULL AND collected = NULL
```

What i'm wondering about is how I would be able to lock these 'wardrobeNo' while the merchant is handling payment, so another merchant does not make order on the same 'wardrobeNo'... just like a restaurant that would link orders to tables.

Is this even a good way to tackle the problem or is there something a lot smarter? Or should I consider thinking about this problem in another way.

Hope it makes sense..

Comment: Hi Sonny, welcome to Stack Overflow. I've edited your question to include code tags around things that looked like code and your query to make it more readable.

Comment: i am unable to understand your question as you are referencing things and logic which is not defined to anybody but you.

Comment: i will try and make it more properly sorry.

Comment: The scope of your question changed quite a lot from the earliest version to this one. Let me know if I got that right: each store has a number of wardrobe slots that is stored somewhere, all wardrobe slots for all stores should be stored in one table, as soon as a slot has been collected, it should again be bookable, right?

Comment: Yes thats 100% correct, thats the scoop of this question explained.

Answer (score 0):

Updated: Instead of taking care of maintaining a sequence yourself, use MySQL's `auto_increment` in combination with a scheduled `alter table` command at midnight:

```
CREATE TABLE idTable (
  idKey INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (idKey)
)
```

And at midnight:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE idTable;
ALTER TABLE idTable AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Then simply add a new record to idTable prior to adding a row to your wardrobe table and use the inserted ID (via `mysql_insert_id()`) to get a daily unique ID.

Comment: i can see your idea here, the only problem is that the DB is getting used by many stores and that way there will a lot of the same wardrobeNo. And storeID was ment to be used to identify what store the entries are linked to. so a foreign key of another table

Comment: Just updated my suggestion, see if that fits better.